# How to develop SSAS so that new and old codes roll up to the same parent?

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I work with a fairly large product database. The business plans to change the product group codes and some names now. We have a lot of history and there will be groups of users who will be interested in using both old and new systems. If I add the new data in the dim table. Below are the table headers: 
**Prodname, old_prod_group, new_prod_group, old_prod_line, new_prod_line,old_prod_nr, new_prod_nr**
The hierarchy is like this: prod_line->Prod_Group->prod_nr

I would like to setup  SSAS in such a way that that old and new prod_nr can roll up to the same prod_group and roll_up to the same prod_line.

There should be a possibility to choose the old names or new names(this I know cna be set in the hierarchies in dimension structure tab) but irrespective of that the fact data should all roll up to the same prod_lines.

so, I think I this comes down to somehow being able to map the old and new prod_grp and telling the cube to consolidate together to show one fact value for a given old/new prod_group pair.

What features or functionalities can help me achive this? Can you please point out to some examples online?

thanks!

Comment: Do you not have any slowly changing dimensions now? Look into Type 3 for this

Answer (score 0):

Are you tracking historical changes in your dimension already? It sounds like you are asking about how to model a slowly changing dimension- is that what you're after?

Comment: no. This is the first time such a change is being proposed that we do from the business side. So, should I be learning about slowly changing dimensions to handle this problem? I have been working on a cube that was handed down to me. I have never built one from scratch but learning on the go now.

Comment: In short yes. Scd type 2 will create a new surrogate key for the product groups that have changed.facts are then attributed to the appropriate SK based on date.  Scd type 3 will hold the previous attribute values too.